# form alter and module load include

Tags: 7, forms

I have module that I alter a form using hook_form_alter. In this alter, I add a submit function to the form that is defined in a include file that I included in the hook_form_alter implementation using the function module_load_include.

It works fine until I submit the form. Drupal does not find my submit function. Is there anyway to make sure that whenever a form is being processed/submit a file is included?

Comment: Can you post code as well ?

Comment: Unfortunately no